# json.loads function not giving python dictionary

Tags: json, python-3.x, dictionary

I am trying to convert the below mentioned json string to python dictionary. I am using python 3's json package for the same. Here is the code that I am using :

```
a = "[{'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}, {'id': 18, 'name': 'Drama'}, {'id': 10751, 'name': 'Family'}, {'id': 10749, 'name': 'Romance'}]"
b = json.loads(json.dumps(a))
print(type(b))
```

And the output that I am getting from the above code is:

> <class 'str'>

I saw the similar questions asked in stackoverflow, but the solutions presented for those questions do not apply to my case.

Comment: `json.dumps(a)` encapsulate it with another set of double quotes, so when you try to `loads` it, you get a string.

Comment: BTW, AFAIK `json.dumps` is designated to take an object (dict) and convert it to a string, so I don't see the point in calling it with a string to begin with.

Comment: Also, in order for a string to properly represent a JSON object, each key must be encapsulated in double quotes, not single quotes. So your input string is not even a valid JSON representation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The json string that you are trying to convert is not properly formatted. Also, you need to only call json.loads to convert string into `dict` or `list`.

The updated code would look like:

```
import json
a = '[{"id": 35, "name": "Comedy"}, {"id": 18, "name": "Drama"}, {"id": 10751, "name": "Family"}, {"id": 10749, "name": "Romance"}]'
b = json.loads(a)
print(type(b))
```

Hope this explains why you are not getting the expected results.

Answer (score 0):

**JSON Array** is enclosed in `[ ]` while **JSON object** is enclosed in `{ }`

> The string in `a` is a *json array* so you can change that into a *list* only.

Your *key and value should be enclosed with double quotes*, that's the requirement to use json library of python.

> `b = json.loads(a)` will give a list of dictionary objects.

To get further dictionary of dictionary you need to associate a key with each individual dictionary.

```
d = dict()
ind = 0
for data in b:
    d[ind] = data
    ind+=1
```

Now the output that you get will be

`{0: {'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}, 1: {'id': 18, 'name': 'Drama'}, 2: {'id': 10751, 'name': 'Family'}, 3: {'id': 10749, 'name': 'Romance'}}`

which is a dictionary of dictionary.

Thank you